# create subclasses or set types as strings?

Tags: java, class

I have a board with pieces of different types. These types only differ in their range and directions they are able to go. Besides that they are **the same**. There are 4 types in total. Would it be better practice if I created 4 subclasses of the class `Piece` or just save the type as a String?
e.g. :

```
public class TypeX extends Piece {...}

public class TypeY extends Piece {...}
```

or

```
public class Piece{
    String type;

    public Piece(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: If they have different *behavior* they should probably be different classes.

Comment: Depends. This is *classic* inheritance, though--you'd be doing additional work to emulate (poorly) an existing type system for no benefit I can see.

Comment: It’s better to have constructor in this case or with getter-setter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should leverage inheritance and create 4 different sub-types. 
Implement the common code, properties, and behaviors in the parent class.

Define in the children anything that is different, such as the movement `behavior`.

What you want is your `class piece` to have a `move` behavior. **However, you want `move` to do something different, depending on the type of piece**. In comes  `polymorphism`. Through this OOP practice, you can implement a different behavior in each of the children classes.

I will take an excerpt from w3schools that explains it adequately.
**Pay extra attention to the animal class and it's children in the example. You can do the exact same thing with the pieces.**

> **Java Polymorphism** 
>   Polymorphism means "many forms", and it occurs when
>   we have many classes that are related to each other by inheritance.
>
> Like we specified in the previous chapter; Inheritance lets us inherit
>   attributes and methods from another class. Polymorphism uses those
>   methods to perform different tasks. This allows us to perform a single
>   action in different ways.
>
> For example, think of a superclass called Animal that has a method
>   called animalSound(). Subclasses of Animals could be Pigs, Cats, Dogs,
>   Birds - And they also have their own implementation of an animal sound
>   (the pig oinks, and the cat meows, etc.):

```
class Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}

class Pig extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The dog says: bow wow");
  }
}
```

Source: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_polymorphism.asp)

Comment: Yes, but that quote misses the point of polymorphism (which is (barely) shown later in that page)